# Do we really need a backup-exec-2010 tag when there's a perfectly good backupexec tag?

Tags: discussion, support, tags, retag-request

Is the rather recent spate of retagging of questions around Backup Exec with `backup-exec-2010` by user KCotreau strictly necessary?

We've already got a perfectly servicable `backupexec` tag, and my impression was that we were moving away from version/year specific tags for pieces of software to more generic tags, see `bind9`->`bind` and `postgres-8.4`>`postgres`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct. Unless there is *overwhelming* evidence that you need a version tag, then you should not use one.

I went ahead and merged them all into [backupexec](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/backupexec)

Comment: I suspected as much. It seemed rather obvious with the entire front page of SF being filled with Backup Exec questions. Throwing this idea out there: would it make more sense to have only moderator/community-approved edits bump a topic to the top of the front page?

Comment: @growse, OT for this question but edits should bump the question so the community is aware of what users are doing. Users are highly discouraged from doing mass edits/retags like that, and even more so during the work week. Devs can mass retag without bumping; if that is needed for a tag post in mSF and they'll take care of it. Back OT, as Jeff suggests, unless one version is substantially different from another, it should not have a version tag.